# Best approach to continuously scan for a string in a streaming buffer

Tags: c, callback, stream, buffer

I have this situation where my function continuously receive data of various length. The data can be anything. I want to find the best way I to hunt for particular string in this data. The solution will require somehow to buffer previous data but I cannot wrap my head around the problem.

Here is an example of the problem:

DATA IN -> [\x00\x00\x01\x23B][][LABLABLABLABLA\x01TO][KEN][BLA\x01]...

if every [...] represents a data chunk and [] represents a data chunk with no items, what is the best way to scan for the string TOKEN?

**UPDATE:**
I realised the question is a bit more complex. the [] are not separators. I just use them to describe the structure of the chunk per above example. Also TOKEN is not a static string per-se. It is variable length. I think the best way to read line by line but than the question is how to read a streaming buffer of variable length into lines.

Comment: What do you want to do when you have found the string? Do you need some data from before it? If not, you can just scan for it using e.g. KMP, and when you reach the end of a chunk, get the next to continue scanning (until found or end of stream).

Comment: Why is this question tagged with 'callback'?

Comment: @junix: since the function "recieves data" in "chunks", I'm guessing the function in question is a callback, called once per chunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I voted to delete my previous answer as my understanding of the question was not correct. I didn't read carefully enouogh and thought that the [] are token delimiters.

For your problem I'd recommend building a small state machine based on a simple counter:
For every character you do something like the following pseudo code:

```
if (received_character == token[pos]) {
    ++pos;
    if (pos >= token_length) {
        token_received = 1;
    }
}
else {
    pos = 0; // Startover
}
```

This takes a minimum of processor cycles and also a minimum of memory aso you don't need to buffer anything except the chunk just received.

Comment: This non-backtracking answer works rather better for the needle "TOKEN", which contains no repeated letters, than it does for other needles. For example it doesn't find the needle "AAB" in the haystack "AAAB", because when it hits the third A it sets `pos` to zero (because it expects a B) and doesn't realize that it has already seen an initial substring of the needle. Of course it's possible to build a finite state machine for any given needle (so if you know the needle now, this might be a good option). But the code to build that machine at runtime is *probably* overkill.

Comment: @SteveJessop Isn't this only an issue for the start letter? Anyway +1 for pointing out this issue. Actually you could build a non deterministic machine having multiple versions of the counter while running through your word. (Would make the implementation a bit more complicated of course)

Comment: yeah, I think it has to involve the first letter. The failure is when some initial segment of the needle occurs elsewhere (and hence gets discarded by the reset), implying that the first letter must occur elsewhere as part of that initial segment. And agreed, you can easily do it using a number of counters equal to the number of bytes that you would have to buffer, if you buffered it. If the questioner wants to do anything clever then there is *plenty* of literature on the subject :-)

Comment: This is indeed error-prone logic, especially considering that the OP has clarified, "... TOKEN is not a static string ...". I'm surprised it got accepted, nonetheless, that doesn't stop me from downvoting. :)

Comment: @Seb Uhm, yes. Maybe you didn't notice, that the Update was inserted after I posted my answer. However I neither see an advantage in your approach nor why mine is to be considered error prone? It is simple and does exactly what the OP asks for.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to search for TOKEN is:

- try to match "TOKEN" starting from position 0 in the stream
- try to match "TOKEN" starting from position 1 in the stream
- etc

So all you need to buffer is a number of bytes from the stream equal to the length of "TOKEN" (5 bytes, or actually 4 will do). At each position try to match "TOKEN", which might require waiting until you have at least 5 bytes read into your buffer. If the match fails, rewind to where you started matching, plus one. Since you never rewind more than the length of the string you're searching for (minus one) that's all the buffer you really need.

The technical issue then is, how to maintain your 5 bytes of buffered data as you read continuously from the stream. One way is a so-called "circular buffer". Another way, especially if the token is small, is to use a larger buffer and whenever you get too near the end, copy the bytes you need to the beginning and start again.

If your function is a callback, called once for each new chunk of data, then you will need to maintain some state from one call to the next to allow for a match that spans two chunks. If you're lucky then your callback API includes a "user data pointer", and you can set that to point to whatever struct you like that includes the buffer. If not, you'll need global or thread-local variables.

If the stream has a high data rate then you might want to think about speeding things up, with the KMP algorithm or otherwise.

Comment: "If the match fails, rewind to where you started matching, plus one" has a weakness.  Answer is not clear on what to do when match succeeds.  A candidate implication is that if the match succeeds, rewind is not needed. A rewind to where you started, plus one is needed should a match succeed or not as the needle/token could partially match itself.  Or simply, "At each position try to match "TOKEN" .. . into your buffer.  Drop the " If the match fails, rewind ...  you really need."

Comment: @chux: I may have misunderstood the context of the question, but I think I was assuming that if the match succeeds (i.e. you've found the whole token) you return `true` and that's the end of it. Depends whether the code only needs to test for the presence of the token, or do more than that. Even if you're supposed to count tokens it's still open whether you should rewind on success or not: does the string `aaaa` contain the token `aa` twice (in which case don't rewind) or three times (in which case rewind)? More specification would be needed.

Comment: Agree with your comments, especially about need for  more specification.

Comment: +1 from me; this is a great answer. This really should have been the accepted answer. I reckon it would have been, if it had an example... and I wouldn't have felt the need to write my own.

Answer (score -1):

If the needle is contained within memory, it could be assumed that you can allocate an equally-sized object to read into (e.g. `char input_array[needle_size];`).

To start the search process, fill that object with bytes from your file (e.g. `size_t sz = fread(input_array, 1, input_size, input_file);`) and attempt a match (e.g. `if (sz == needle_size && memcmp(input_array, needle, needle_size) == 0) { /* matched */ }`.

If the match fails or you want to continue searching after a successful match, advance the position forward by one byte (e.g. `memmove(input_array, input_array + 1, input_size - 1); input_array[input_size - 1] = fgetc(input_file);` and try again.

A concern was raised that this idea copies too many bytes around, in the comments. While I don't believe that this concern has a significant merit (as there is no evidence of significant value), the copies can be avoided by using a circular array; we insert new characters at `pos % needle_size` and compare the regions before and after that boundary as though they are the tail and head respectively. For example:

```
void find_match(FILE *input_file, char const *needle, size_t needle_size) {
    char input_array[needle_size];
    size_t sz = fread(input_array, 1, needle_size, input_file);
    if (sz != needle_size) {
        // No matches possible
        return;
    }

    setvbuf(input_file, NULL, _IOFBF, BUFSIZ);
    unsigned long long pos = 0;
    for (;;) {
        size_t cursor = pos % needle_size;
        int tail_compare = memcmp(input_array, needle + needle_size - cursor, cursor),
            head_compare = memcmp(input_array + cursor, needle, needle_size - cursor);
        if (head_compare == 0 && tail_compare == 0) {
            printf("Match found at offset %llu\n", pos);
        }
        int c = fgetc(input_file);
        if (c == EOF) {
            break;
        }
        input_array[cursor] = c;
        pos++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this solution is not only way too complicated for what the code should do it's also a waste of CPU power and memory. E.g. Copying around the whole sample all the time is very inefficient.

Comment: @junix Firstly, before we can consider speed we need to consider correctness. If it doesn't work 100% of the time, it's buggy and that needs to be fixed. Once it works 100% of the time, we can profile it to determine whether or not it's the most significant bottleneck in the bigger picture that is the entire piece of software. Do you have any evidence to suggest that this is the most significant bottleneck? With which parameters will this code typically slow down significantly? I'm not confident that you understand what you're talking about...

Comment: @junix As I said, I don't think you understand what you're talking about. Otherwise you'd understand that profilers identify these things you may not yet understand called *cache misses*; it's those *cache misses* (among other kinds of *misses*) that are likely to cause significant bottlenecks. That aside, the significant bottleneck here is the IO, not because of `getchar` ([test it with `setvbuf`, I dare you](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/2q2zxe/weekly_18_holiday_code_a_time_of_sharing/cnf265o))  but because **the underlying filesystem is slow**. You have the same problem.

Comment: @junix P.S. There is no requirement that the *first chunk* be *the size of the token*; I'm not sure where you misunderstood that from... This just reinforces my concern that you don't know what you're talking about. Furthermore, when `needle` is a repetitive string like `"ololo"` and the stream contains overlapping instances of that string like `"olololo"` (there are two matches there), your algorithm will fail (it only identifies one match). Feel free to ping me when you've eaten some humble pie. I'm sure we can learn much together...

Comment: Please refrain from talking about things you don't understand. **Do you have any evidence to suggest that my code will be the most significant bottleneck?** If not, then perhaps it'd be a good idea spending precious time to consider other parts for optimisation. If `needle` contains 10 times a and stream contains 9 times a followed by b, then stream will read that 9 times a followed by b into `input_array`, compare against `needle` and with one call to `memcmp` a mismatch will be identified after 10 characters are compared, once. Your code needs to compare the same 10 characters, once, also.